# How to send and receive in a PROMELA process without timeout / deadlock?

Tags: timeout, deadlock, send, promela

I cannot wrap my head around this PROMELA problem: I have N processes ("pc") which may both send and receive messages over a channel ("to_pc"). Each process has its own channel over which it receives messages.
For a process to be able to receive, I have to keep it in a loop which checks the channel for incoming messages. As a second loop option the process sends a message to all other channels.

However, in simulation mode, this always causes a timeout, without anything being sent at all. My theory so far is that I created a deadlock where all processes want to send at once, causing them all to be unable to receive (since they are stuck in their "send" part of the code).

So far I have been unable to resolve this problem. I have tried to use a global variable as a semaphore to "forbid" sending, so that only one channel may send. However, this did not change the results. My only other idea is to use a timeout as the trigger for the sending, but this does not seem right to me at all.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
#define N 4

mtype={request,reply}

typedef message {
    mtype type;
    byte target;
    byte sender;
};

chan to_pc[N] = [0] of {message}

inline send() {
    byte j = 0;
    for (j : 0 .. N-1) {
        if
        :: j != address ->
            to_pc[j]!msg;
        :: else;
        fi
    }
}

active [N] proctype pc(){
    byte address = _pid;
    message msg;

    do
    :: to_pc[address]?msg -> /* Here I am receiving a message. */
        if
        ::msg.type == request->
            if
            :: msg.target == address ->
                d_step {
                    msg.target = msg.sender
                    msg.sender = address;
                    msg.type = reply;
                }
                send();
            :: else
            fi
        :: msg.type == reply;
        :: else;
        fi
    :: /* Here I want to send a message! */
        d_step {
            msg.target = (address + 1) % N;
            msg.sender = address;
            msg.type = request;
        }
        send();
    od
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can write a *full-fledged* working version of your *source code* if you want, but perhaps it is sufficient to *highlight* the source of the issue you are dealing with and let you *have fun* solving it.

---

**Branching Rules**

- any branch with an *executable* condition can be taken, *non-deterministically*
- if there is *no* branch with an *executable* condition, the *else* branch is taken
- if there is *no* branch with an *executable* condition and *no else* branch, then the process hangs till when one of the conditions becomes true

---

Consider this

```
1: if
2:    :: in?stuff -> ...
3:    :: out!stuff -> ...
4: fi
```

where `in` and `out` are both *synchronous channels* (size is `0`).

Then

- if someone is *sending* on the other end of `in` then `in?stuff` is executable, otherwise it is not
- if someone is *receiving* on the other end of `out` then `out!stuff` is executable, otherwise it is not
- the process *blocks* at line `1:` up until when at least one of the two conditions is *executable*.

Compare that code to this

```
1: if
2:    :: true -> in?stuff; ...
3:    :: true -> out!stuff; ...
4: fi
```

where `in` and `out` are again *synchronous channels* (size is `0`).

Then

- both branches have an *executable* condition (`true`)
- the process immediately **commits itself** to either *send* or *receive* something, by non-deterministically choosing to execute a branch either at line `2:` or `3:`
- if the process chooses `2:` then it *blocks* if `in?stuff` is *not executable*, even when `out!stuff` would be executable
- if the process chooses `3:` then it *blocks* if `out!stuff` is *not executable*, even when `in!stuff` would be executable

Your code falls in the latter situation, since all the instructions within `d_step { }` are [executable](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/d_step.html) and your process commits to *send* way too early.

---

**To sum up**: in order to fix your model, you should *refactor* your code so that it's always possible to *jump* from *send* to *receive* mode and viceversa. *Hint: get rid of that inline code, separate the decision to send from actual sending.*

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. It in fact solved the problem I described. Now I only have to find a way to set the message content before it is being sent. In the example it is basically constant, but I simplified it to stick to the issue. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @K.Huber provide an `else` to each `out!stuff` statement, s.t. `else` would get you back at the beginning of the `main loop` and whenever you go back to `send` you resume from the latest index `j` you were able to send rather than starting from scratch. In this way, every time a *send* cannot be performed you have the chance to evaluate whether a *receive* can be done instead.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the "dubious use of else combined with i/o" error when run in verification mode?

Comment: Yes of course, but then again you can get rid of that by making the *synchronous* channel *asynchronous* and using *empty()/nempty()* as branch *conditions* instead of *else* directly. It was just easier to explain that way.